# The python requests module does not persist session

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I am trying to upload csv file using python requests module but i am unable to persist the session. Every call i make is trying to start new HTTPS connection. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: @pvg:  I tried to use it but it did not work for me.

Comment: You should be posting what you tried, what you expected to happen, what actually happened, how you determined what did and did not work, etc. As it is, nobody can really help you.

Comment: @pvg : here is my code

Comment: You are mixing HTTP connection and session in your question. A session typically spans many HTTP requests and is usually maintained through cookies. Each HTTP request can still create a new HTTP connection.

Comment: @zvone requests tries to use urllib3 connection pooling, keep-alive, etc whenever you use its Session api. It sort of bundles it all together, it is not strictly a cookie-tracking session.

Comment: @pvg:@pvg:
with open(filename,'rb') as fileobj:
    files = {'file': fileobj,
            'stateID':(None,'1234'),
            'selectedOrgId':(None,'1234'),
            'reportUpload':(None,'false'),
            'date':(None,datetime.datetime.now(tzlocal())),
            'milliSec':(None,(datetime.now().microsecond)/1000),
            'name':(None,'uploaddFile')
            }
    resp = s.post(upload_url,data=None,files=files,headers=upload_headers)
and this call starts a new https connection.

Comment: you want to edit your question with that stuff and keep it as short and relevant as possible.

Comment: @pvg That may be true, but I am saying it is not clear what the question is about. If it is really about HTTP connections, the title and text should say that clearly.